# How to compare strings together

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this to where a user presses a number, and after that they type in the string of the available choices they want to see. So far everything works, except when the user types in the string it doesn't give the preferred output.. *shows email instead of color, user id, etc. Here is my code.. Thanks again!

```
public static void printStuff(Record[] objects) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the number and record name you would like to see");
   int x = in.nextInt();
   String bean = in.next();


        if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.equals("email")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getEmail());
        }
       else if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.equals("name")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getfirstName());
        }

       else if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.matches("last name")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getlastName());
        }

       else if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.matches("balance")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getBalance());
        }

       else if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.matches("color")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getColor());
        }

       else if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 && bean.matches("idnumber")) {
            System.out.println(objects[x].getnumID());
        }
 }
```

Comment: When you use `||` and `&&` in an expression always use parentheses to make it clear what the precedence is.

Comment: And learn about <= and >=, and about using variables and nestid if to avoid repeating yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In all the if conditions, `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so you must change the conditions to:

`(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) && bean.equals("email")`.

This corresponds to the logic you want, if `x` is some value in 1 through 5 AND bean equals `"email"`. However, look into comparison operators, because you can simplify this to:

`(1 <= x && x <= 5) && bean.equals("email")`.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try, always avoid retyping of cases and make your code more efficient.

```
public static void printStuff(Record[] objects) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the number and record name you would like to see");
   int x = in.nextInt();
   String bean = in.next();


        if (x >= 1 && x =< 5 ) {
            if (bean.equals("email"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getEmail());
            else if (bean.equals("name"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getfirstName());
            else if (bean.matches("last name"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getlastName());
            else if (bean.matches("balance"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getBalance());
            else if (bean.matches("color"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getColor());
            else if (bean.matches("idnumber"))
               System.out.println(objects[x].getnumID());
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

perhaps a little easier to read:

```
if (1 <= x && x <= 5) {
    switch (bean) {
        case "email": 
            System.out.println(record.email);
            break;
        case "name": 
            System.out.println(record.firstName);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Using the [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) (Java 13, `--enable-preview`):

```
if (1 <= x && x <= 5) {
    System.out.println(switch (bean) {
        case "email" -> record.email;
        case "name" -> record.firstName;
        case "last name"-> record.lastName;
        ...
        default -> "unrecognized " + bean;
        // default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
    });
}
```

Or, if nothing should be executed for unknown `bean`:

```
if (1 <= x && x <= 5) {
    switch (bean) {
        case "email" -> System.out.println(record.email);
        case "name" -> System.out.println(record.firstName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Using switch expression can't handle `bean` having none of the known values.

Comment: @Andreas It can through usage of `default:`

Comment: Only if something needs to be printed, which code is the question suggest is not the case (there is no final `else` clause).

Comment: In which case no `default` is required. If the value doesn't match any case the code will continue.

Comment: the switch **expression** (2nd code snippet above) requires an `default`, unless all values are given (only `enum`s):, since an expression always must have a result (or throw an Exception). JEP:  "The cases of a switch expression must be exhaustive; for any possible value there must be a matching switch label."

Comment: I believe this is wrong. From the JLS: `If no case matches and there is no default label, then no further action is taken and the switch statement completes normally.`

Comment: @bbnumber2 can you please point me where you found that? (hard to believe that an switch expression can complete normally with out any result)

Comment: At 14.11:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

Comment: @bbnumber2 well that is definitively for switch **statement**, my comment (clearly in bold) is about the switch **expression** (the 2nd code snippet in my answer, somehow I fell like repeating myself), that is a preview (that need `--enable-preview`) in Java 13 (BTW Java 7 is pretty old....)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you might solve it by reducing your conditions. This can still be done better. The if'elses kill me.

```
public static void printStuff(Record[] objects) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number and record name you would like to see");

    int x = in.nextInt();

    String bean = in.next();

    Record record = objects[x];

    if (x >= 1 && x <= 5) {
        if (bean.equals("email")) {
            System.out.println(record.email);
        } else if (bean.equals("name")) {
            System.out.println(record.firstName);
        } else if (bean.equals("last name")) {
            System.out.println(record.lastName);
        } else if (bean.equals("balance")) {
            System.out.println(record.balance);
        } else if (bean.equals("idnumeric")) {
            System.out.println(record.numId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add brackets appropriately.

```
(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) && bean.equals("email")
```